# How to remove script tag from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I would like to remove script tag from UIWebView

The methods I try is using

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].remove()"]
```

but it it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
NSString *jsConstant = "
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    if(element){
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }"
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsConstant]
```

if is it is not working you can debug this in Safari.(Develop->select device->it will inspectable web view)